# Trying to eliminate a character

Tags: php

```
$message=$this->filter($_POST['suggestion']);

protected function filter($mail)
{
    if(strpos($mail,"<") !== false)
    {
        $mail = "message entered is invalid";
    }
    else
    {
        $mail = $mail;
    }

    return $mail;
}
```

Sure I'm doing something wrong here, but if `$_POST["suggestion"]` contains a "<" then it should return my predefined message. It doesn't work: it always return the same message regardless if the "<" is in there or not.

Comment: Is this all your code? As it stands, it has several errors. You are familiar with OOP right?

Comment: Above your first line, do var_dump($_POST['suggession']) and see what the value is. suggession is not spelt correctly, but maybe that is how your code is

Comment: yeah im terrible in my spelling and no would you really want me tp post all the code its just an extract so you can see what am doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use preg_match

```
function filter($mail)
{
    if(preg_match("/</", $mail))
    {
      $mail="message entered is invalid";
     }

   return $mail;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: i Actually wanted to use the faster method but since this is the only answer differing from my own that works it gets tick

Comment: preg_match is mainly when you need to use regex

Comment: @alex_zander: using this function is not faster that mine!

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
<?
function filter($mail)
{
    if(strpos($mail,"<")!==false)
    {
       $mail="message entered is invalid";
    }

    return $mail;
}

echo filter("something");
echo filter("some < thing");
?>
```

[DEMO](http://codepad.org/a8Lje5pj)

You don't need the `else` part. And the rest of your code is working fine.

The `!==` part it's ok! see: http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php